# Is MVC less probable to double-postback than ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, double, postback

After years of working in `ASP.net`, I just saw some scary stuff happening in `ASP.net`.

Some pages started doing double post-back (once every 80 000 times that the page is used), and in some instances duplicate entries were added into the DB.

Now there are many possible reasons for this, e.g
the single [empty image](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/02/aspnet-double-postback-bug-strikes.html)
 but 
also  [networking](http://microsoft.public.inetserver.iis.narkive.com/YJ1nPfbt/iislog-sc-win32-status-64-and-sc-status-200) issues .

My question: 
Is `MVC` less probable to have double post-backs than `ASP.net`
or

because `MVC` is hosted in IIS, and there are so many reason that it could happen, that people are still experiencing it (even though MVC is newer than ASP.net)?

I dont know if moving our project to MVC will help alleviate these issues. These did not happen because we allowed double-clicks on buttons.

I'm in a situation where I need advice on suggesting architectural design changes, hence this question please.

Comment: Have you looked into other ways of preventing double postback? Good resource here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1241973.aspx?prevent+double+postback

Comment: Yes, we covered all buttons, its mostly network issues causing our problems. Hence the question, because both are still using IIS, are MVC users experiencing as many double postbacks?

Comment: @PeterPitLock - It's not "network issues" that's causing the double postback.  It's the users that are doing it.  It's the network issues that cause the users to try and refresh the page though, which causes it to post a second time.  This is nothing specific to IIS, it can happen with any server or any technology.  Also the empty image is also not a "double postback", at most it's a "double get", and again it's nothing to do with IIS or asp.net, it's a because the browser interprets an empty src as a request to the current url.

Comment: Moving away from ASP.NET is not going to stop your double-postback issues, it's not a platform-specific issue. You should look at the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: @PeterPitLock - If you want to prevent these kinds of problems, there's a relatively simple way to do it.  When the user requests a page that you need to ensure isn't double posted, add a hidden field with a unique code, say a guid.  When the page is posted, check this guid against a session variable of "already posted" values, and if it's there, don't complete the transaction.  Of course you have to be careful not to create a race condition, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, @ErikFunkenbusch, the reason I'm suspecting network issues is that in today's event specifically, IIS returned a sc-win32-status code of 64 - 64 (0x40): 'The specified network name is no longer available'. IIS then proceeded to post the page again (without any user intervention) because of the failed return code, and then the duplicate was experienced.

Comment: @PeterPitLock - IIS never "posts the page again" without user intervention.  What a 64 means is that the connection is no longer valid for the response.  IIS will simply abort the transaction.  The user, on the other hand, may press F5 because they see a spinning cursor and repost.  But IIS won't repost it.  Also, be careful that there aren't proxies in between, because proxies can do strange things.

Comment: thanks @ErikFunkenbusch, I'm still investigating, i would not have thought of the proxy at all, but it is in fact going through a proxy. The reason I thought it could not be the user, is that we record the time that the entries were made, and the EXACT time- up to a 1000th of a second, was the same - the user couldnt have pressed F5 in 1000th of a second - but you pointed me in the right direction I reckon- I think the proxy is worth looking into. Thanks so far!

Comment: @PeterPitLock - What do you mean by "record the time the entries were made"?  If the time is based on a client-side value (generated in javascript) then this value would be the same because the request was duplicated.  If it's a server side value then it's not possible for it to be the same because a second request would cause a new value to be generated (regardless of where it came from).  Unless the time is somehow being recorded by an intermediate proxy and inserted into the request, I don't see how what you say is possible to detect.